# Sending a decrypted string in an email using php

Tags: php, mysql, md5

What I'm trying to do is to insert users into a table with a randomised password (works fine till here) and on successful submission of the form I want to send email to the registered user their password. This is what I've got so far:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
require_once 'login.php'; 

  $OK = false;
  $conn = new mysqli ($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Connection Failed");
  $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();


  $sql = 'INSERT INTO users (user_email, user_name, user_pref, user_password)
          VALUES(?, ?, ?, des_encrypt(substring(md5(rand()),1,8)))';
  if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    // bind parameters and execute statement
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_POST['user_email'], $_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_pref'], $_POST['user_password']);
    // execute and get number of affected rows
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
      $OK = true;
    }
  }
  if ($OK) {
    header('Location: confirm.php');
    exit;
  } else {
    $error = $stmt->error;
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Add User</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Add User</h1>
<?php if (isset($error)) {
  echo "<p>Error: $error</p>";
} ?>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>
    <label for="user_email">User email:</label>
    <input name="user_email" type="text" class="widebox" id="user_email">
  </p>
    <p>
    <label for="user_name">User name:</label>
    <input name="user_name" type="text" class="widebox" id="user_name">
  </p>
    <p>
    User role: <select name = "user_pref">
    <option value = "BLU">Blue</option>
    <option value = "YEL">Yellow<option>
    <option value = "GRE">GREEN</option>
    </select>
</p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Register New User" id="insert">
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The sql statement to select the decrypted password and user email would be:

```
$sql = 'select user_email, des_decrypt(user_password) from users where person_id = max(person_id)';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql)
```

and it would go inside this function:

```
if ($OK) {
}
```

however I couldn't get it to work with a basic mail function. Does anyone have any ideas that would help me ?

Thanks

Comment: `des_encrypt(substring(md5(rand()),1,8))` ... what's that for?

Comment: And, where are you trying to send the email?

Comment: @Jack I thought it'd be for decrypting the password...

Comment: @Jack I'm trying to send it to the user who got added to the table. So if I register you on the system, it should generate a randomised password, and send it to you by decrypting it

Comment: It's recommended to NOT send passwords via email; also, I would ask the user for a password as part of the registration; then you store that using **bcrypt**. Passwords are not meant to be reversed.

Comment: @Jack ah I see, thanks for the recommendation. So do I instead send an email to users to ask them to choose a password ? Would my idea not work at all ?

Comment: @Jack, elmify its one way to get a random string of 8 characters - but yes, it is common practice to a) let the user chose a password and b) encrypt it in a way that is not (easily) reversed. elmify: what exactly is your problem with the mail: the password or the mail as such?

Comment: @cypherabe thanks for the advice ! yes that'd work better I suppose, I was going to let the user change their password in the system later on. MY problem was that I couldn't send it to the user. If I do it your way, will I need to send  a link to user to a page where they can choose a password ?

Comment: @Jack I suppose I still need to be able to send passwords in an email because I'm trying to develop another page (FOrgot password) where I need to select the users password and email it to them.

Comment: @elmify please allow me to put it in simple words. You _don't_ send decrypted passwords to anyone because *you* should *not* be able to do so. The proper way to go about this is to ask the user to create a secure password and only the user should know about it. All instances of the password on your entire system should be _always encrypted_ . In fact PCI compliant companies will frown upon any such practices. For an interesting take on this check out: http://serverfault.com/questions/293217

Comment: No, forgot password will generate a reset token that's mailed to the user. Upon using the token they get to choose another password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different topics to answer here:

1. a more typical password handling would be :
2. let the user enter a password in the registration form (use a "re-enter" field, check that both fields contain the same string, maybe use a javascript snippet to force a certain password complexity - there should be plenty available online)
3. store the hash of the password in the database, use a difficult to reverse crypt function (bcrypt in SQL or [crypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) in PHP)
4. for even more security, use time() or rand() to create a pseudo random salt, concatenate this to the user's password, use the concatenated string in the encryption function. Don't forget to store the salt in the DB, too
5. provide a "I forgot my password" function, use the classic double authentication: user asks for password, you send an e-mail to the registered e-mail address for this user containing a one-time token, the user has to enter the token (or click the link where the token is set as a GET parameter) and can only now change his password.
6. Mail in PHP (and other scripting languages) can be a tricky thing.
   PHP as such has no build in mail client, but needs to use standalone e-mail components. You or your admin need to make sure that

- the server provides e-mail functionality (for example the sendmail package in a linux system)
- the server is allowed to send mails to the world. Meaning, Firewall / Router / Proxys must allow traffic on the mail port

for further information regarding mailing with php look in the manual:
[mail](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php)

Comment: ah I see, thanks for the explanation. The reason why I'm generating a password is because a person cannot register themselves on the system, someone else (their manager who has the privilege) needs to register that user. that's why I would like to generate a password and email it to them and maybe ask the user to change it as soon as they log on (and not give them full access to the application until they do so). Isn't that a good option ?

Comment: sure, that is a good (and often used) solution in such a situation